# SQL Query for a previous individuals record by ID or date

Tags: sql-server

Below is the start of a query which is based around 2 tables (c_master & c_datah) of horse race results. Each race has a unique ID, c_id in c_master table & c_masterid in c_datah table.

While I can query the whole database. This query in summary is to find how the performance of all Jockeys (c_jockey column) when they are riding the Favourite as detailed by a match in c_fav column. The end of the query (not included) performs calculations upon the resulting data.

**The issue I wish help with is to add a further item to the search. Namely when the horse being ridden has won it’s previous race.**

The c_fpos column indicates a finishing position where 1 means the winner of the race, 2 second. Horses which do not complete a race have an alphabetical letter to denote the reason for the failure.
The unique ID mentioned earlier increments every day and each race taking place upon that day.
Therefore we will have a horse that have run multiple times but we wish the information from the row in the table earlier than the current one for an individual name. The name is stored in column c_horse.

**How do I look back historically to add an additional statement to the sections ending ‘Total_Match’ & ‘Total_Win’ ?**

```
DECLARE @From_Date smalldatetime;
DECLARE @To_Date smalldatetime;
DECLARE @Course varchar(225);
DECLARE @jockey nvarchar(50);



SET @From_Date = '';
SET @To_Date = '';
SET @jockey = N'';
SET @Course = '';



SELECT DISTINCT
       c_jockey,
       ISNULL((SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), c_pfrom) / CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), c_pto)) AS Differance
               FROM datah
                    INNER JOIN master ON datah.c_masterid = master.c_id
               WHERE c_jockey = m.c_jockey
                 AND c_favs IN ('CFav', 'Fav', 'JFav')
                 AND c_fpos = '1'
                 AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, @From_Date, 103)
                  AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, @To_Date, 103)))
                 AND (c_course = @Course
                   OR @Course = '')
                 AND c_pfrom <> ''
                 AND c_pto <> ''
               GROUP BY c_jockey),
              0) AS Win,
       ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(c_favs) AS Win_Count
               FROM datah
                    INNER JOIN master ON datah.c_masterid = master.c_id
               WHERE c_jockey = m.c_jockey
                 AND c_favs IN ('CFav', 'Fav', 'JFav')
                 AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, @From_Date, 103)
                  AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, @To_Date, 103)))
                 AND (c_course = @Course
                   OR @Course = '')
               GROUP BY c_jockey),
              0) AS Total_Match,
       ISNULL((SELECT
                   --c_favs,c_pfrom,c_pto, 
                   COUNT(c_favs) AS Win_Count
               FROM datah
                    INNER JOIN master ON datah.c_masterid = master.c_id
               WHERE c_jockey = m.c_jockey
                 AND c_favs IN ('CFav', 'Fav', 'JFav')
                 AND c_fpos = '1'
                 AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) >= CONVERT(datetime, @From_Date, 103)
                  AND (CONVERT(datetime, c_date, 103) <= CONVERT(datetime, @To_Date, 103)))
                 AND (c_course = @Course
                   OR @Course = '')
               GROUP BY c_jockey),
              0) AS Total_Win,
```

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. It helps easily distinguish specific code blocks, and sections, and also makes finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: For Previous Race Add `Lag` function, totals are `Sum(...) over (partition by ...)` , I think CTE will make your query more readable,